# (Matlab) How to extract matrix elements corresponding to row and column subscripts stored in cell arrays

Tags: matlab

I am stuck with cell arrays and indexing.
I have a matrix M and I want to extract only those elements with specific row- and column- indices.
These indices are stored in cell arrays: C1 (for row subscripts) and C2 for column subscripts.

This is the way I did it:

```
my1Func = @(x,y) M(x,y);
Sub_M = cellfun(@(x,y) myFunc(x,y), C1, C2, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

However, the result is not what I want. I only need to take same-index values from C1 and C2: Sub_M {4} should have only those elements of M with the row and column subscripts having the same index in the respective arrays. For example, Sub_M (2,2) should be:

```
M(C1{4}(2),C2{4}(2));
```

I do not know how to do that.
Note: cells in C1 have different size, same for cells in C2. But the first cell in C1 has the same size as the first in C2, the second in C1 as the second in C2 and so on...

Can you help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you possibly provide an example of your cell array M and what you want as your output?

Comment: My cell array is a 1x4 double cell. I want to extract specific matrix values which correspond to specific row- and col- subscripts and this must be done for each cell of my cell array M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your question clearly, but I suspect this is what your are looking for:

```
% Create a 4x3 matrix
matrix = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 10 11 12];

% Create coordinates for elements at: (1,1), (2,3), (3,2) and (4,1)
rowIdxs = { 1 2 3 4};
colIdxs = { 1 3 2 1};

% Convert to matrix
rowIdxs = cell2mat(rowIdxs);
colIdxs = cell2mat(colIdxs);

% Get linear indexes
linearIdxs = ((colIdxs - 1) * size(matrix, 1)) + rowIdxs; 

% Extract desired elements
result = matrix(linearIdxs);
```

Result is:

```
result =
     1     6     8    10
```

In MATLAB, you can access elements using linear indexes (they are ordered column-wise). Element at `(1,2)` is `1`; element at `(2,1)` is `2`; element at `(3,1)` is `3`; and so on.

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for `sub2ind` function

Comment: But why is not working with row- and col- subscripts? Why is it different if I convert them to linear index?